# Replace content inside bracket with given content Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to replace the below content in Notepad++

```
{\abc {a}}, {\abc {c}}, {\def {a}}
{\agh {a}}, {\abc {c}}, {\def {a}}
{\def {a}} {\abc {a}}, {\abc {c}}
```

such that the result as follows:

```
{\def {a}}
{\def {a}}
{\def {a}}
```

I know how to replace all content inside bracket with `\{.*\}` in regular mode, but I don't know how to replace with given content. In this case is "\abc", or "\a*" in general.
Do we have any optimal method to filter similar characters like  {\abc {a}}, {\agh {a}}, {\abc {c}} has same part "{\a" and keep only the difference with the above?
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to keep allways the last brackets? or the brakets that have `\def` in them? Are every thing in a single line? Please, add some test cases with expected result.

Comment: I just edited my question. Thank you

Comment: So you want to keep literally `{\def {a}}` only and remove everything else? What about a line that doesn't content `{\def {a}}` like: `{\abc {a}}, {\abc {c}}`? Do you want to remove the whole line included line break or keep the line break? Is it literally `\def` and `a` or could it be `\dab` or \dxyz``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `\{\\a[^{]*\{[^{]*\}\}` if you have always 1-level nested brackets

but just two points :

- To replace brackets with any content use `\{[^{]*\{[^{]*\}\}` instead of `\{.*\}`, else the entire expression `{\abc {a}}, {\abc {c}}, {\def {a}}` will match.
- `\abc` doesn't match with `\a*` which matches with expressions like `\`, `\a` or `\aaaaaaaa`

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression for more information

Comment: Thank you, but in the case
{\abc }, {\aaa}, {\aac}, {\def }
which is the best way to keep only {\def }

Comment: I edited but you should try to understand the syntax to be able to do it yourself